# Django rest framework best practices

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, get

I was wondering what would be the best approach . I've been agonizing on what is the best way to accomplish a given task. It is a project with a react frontend and django rest framework backend. I am working on the backend with the django rest framework .

**Task:**

1. To query a user by their phonenumber which is stored as the username field.
2. To add a user to a profile model and add an extra field which is required by the profile model
3. To create the new profile with the user as the profiles user .

e.g

```
Profile Model:

User - ForeignKey
ExtraField - Charfield
```

My question is which of these solutions is better .

1. Should I build a url like this : domain/users/{phonenumber} and post the Extra field
   and query the user like this.

```
def get_object(self):
     return get_object_or_404(User,username=self.kwargs['phonenumber'])

user= get_object()
```

or

2. Should I post both the phonenumber and the extrafield and query the user from the backend like this.

```
user = get_object_or_404(User,username=request.data.get('phonenumber'))
```

both work but which would be the best practice if it even matters at all.

Answer (score 2):

If you just starting a django project the best way would be to create a custom user model with only fields you need for your user.
See docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model).